# Move or remove the wallch button on top left

Tags: wallch

[image]

Wallch has a little circular button on the top left which changes the wallpaper when clicked but it's covering the x button. How can I move it from there (maybe to bottom right) or, if this is not possible, how do I remove the button? I looked in the preferences.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this ? This happened to me today after a wallch update. I am on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: no sadly and it's bugging me. I'm also 14.04

Comment: I think a current workaround is to close and reopen wallch by right-clicking that icon. it disappears then

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Strangely though, if I left click on it, the window which is open, closes and the icon disappears. Wallch is still running but no more icon !